# How to make an image featured when there are multiple images uploaded using CCK field?

Tags: drupal, cck, imagefield

I am trying create an image gallery using the cck image field with multiple image upload enabled. I am fine with everything but stuck at one thing. I want to mark an image so that it becomes the album cover. I have googled a lot but did not come up with any solution. So can anyone here please help me or at least show me the correct path.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've not seen Drupal image gallery, sorry if it does not answer you.
Can you not use Views to select any CCK field?

Comment: Yes, I am fully okay with my photo gallery and views related stuffs. What I need now is in the image uploader form, need a checkbox with each images to make it album cover. A close functionality available in facebook album edit options.

Comment: They you'll need to create a node with as many image fields, along with checkboxes to indicate albut cover.

Comment: What about the Flag module, to flag what image is the cover?

Answer (score -1):

may be this is not what you are looking for, but you can quickly solve this using one of this methods.

one way is to make another CCK field just for album covers. Down side on this method is that one of images would have to be uploaded twice.

Other way is when you use views for making album lists you include imagefield and set it up so it shows only first image in list by setting: "Group multiple values" to true, "show 1 value", "starting form 0".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I also thought such solution but situation is something like album creator will choose the album cover from uploaded images. So cant go with the grouping views. Anyway thanks for your time.